# Renault Megane 1.9 dci 2002 it make loud noice above 40km/h

Tags: belt, engine-load

So car was on a small service and i pick up the car 2 days later from my sister she say the engine dont make any wierd noice. Then i drive it for about 30min and i realise the right side on the engine is making louder noice from above 40km/h. Noise is like from belt i am not shure because it will make noise below 40km/h can some ome solve this problem?

Comment: I forgot to mention it stil make loud noise and when I release the gas.

Comment: so this sound started after the sevice? what parts got replaced during the sevice,exactly what was done during the sevice?please take a look at the documents you got from the shop.what engine parts has been changed during the lifetime of your car,oil pump,alternator,waterpump.

Comment: all  the pullys and belts are at the right side of your engine so you need to focus on this area,take a look at each of the pullys and look for rubber deposits on/around the pullys.